# K8s ConfigMap Properties mounted and loaded from file system does not work when refresh is called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have a Spring Boot app deployed to K8s. I'm using ConfigMap instance to mount my `application.properties` into the Pod by running the Spring Cloud Kubernetes application and having Spring Cloud Kubernetes read them from the file system

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-k8s-minion
server.port=8080
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.paths=/etc/app-config/application.properties

management.endpoint.refresh.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

pom.xml:

```xml
    <spring-boot.version>2.6.7</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring.cloud.k8s.version>2.1.2</spring.cloud.k8s.version>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration()
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "minion")
public class MinionConfig {

    private String type = "generic-minion";

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I have a rest endpoint exposing the configs and can verify that the properties are loaded into my app when it loads.

If I update my config:

```sh
kubectl edit configmap -n development spring-cloud-k8s-minion -o yaml
```

and `exec` into my pod/container to see if the new config is reloaded I can see the new values. So far so good.

Now, if I call `/actuator/refresh` the new value is not loaded into my app. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  found the fix. I have to move `spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.paths` to `bootstrap.properties`.

At least to me it was not clear where to put `spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.paths`. If you check the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/) you cannot find anything regarding the location of it.

Overall, we have to guess between `bootstrap.properties` and `application.proeprties`!